# DJI Android SDK crashes with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, dji-sdk

I'm using the DJI Android SDK version 4.10, using the Proguard file defined [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/blob/master/proguard-project.txt) as requested.

Release builds crash when registering with the SDK, with the following issue:

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.a$a.a(Unknown Source:0)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.a.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.g.a(Unknown Source:26)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.AppActivationManager.init(Unknown Source:25)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initParams(Unknown Source:115)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initSDKManager(Unknown Source:141)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.access$1300(Unknown Source:0)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager$5.run(Unknown Source:121)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(Unknown Source:26)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.a$1.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.a.d(Unknown Source:34)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.a.<init>(Unknown Source:21)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.a.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.realname.aircraftbinding.a$a.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
AndroidRuntime:     ... 9 more
```

I'm using the following `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName "0.3.0"
        ...
    }
    ...
    ndk {
            // On x86 devices that run Android API 23 or above, if the application is targeted with API 23 or
            // above, FFmpeg lib might lead to runtime crashes or warnings.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    
    // DJI Requirements
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    /* Kotlin */
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    /* Android */
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    /* Constraint Layout */
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    /* Recycler View */
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    /* Android Lifecycle */
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    kapt 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'

    /* Room components */
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    /* License list */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:16.0.2'

    /* Dependency Injection */
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:1.0.2'

    /* DJI stuff */
    implementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.10'
    compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.10'

    /* Geographic Lib for distance calculation */
    implementation 'net.sf.geographiclib:GeographicLib-Java:1.49'

    /* Test */
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'
}
```

Looking online seems to suggest that this might be an issue with Proguard, Gson and Jack. I've not seen any answers to this issue though.

Comment: contact dji dev. no way you can get answer here.

Comment: They have no idea. They just told me to use the Proguard file I'm already using.

Comment: hahaha typical DJI altitude. then find DJI dealers they might have in house developer doing similar thing.

Comment: Where you able to figure this out?  I'm also seeing something similar.

Comment: Yeah I think this was either an issue with R8 (revert back to proguard), or using androidX